# HTTP 406 not acceptable response header fiddler

Tags: json, http, elasticsearch, fiddler, http-status-code-406

I am using `fiddler 4` as a frond-end service for `elasticsearch`.

I'm trying to store a document into index using API following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_installation.htm).

Here's my sample json as request body:

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

API : `http://localhost:9200/food/fruit`
method :`POST HTTP/1.1`

Here's the response:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in their [doc.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests), *"Starting from Elasticsearch 6.0, all REST requests that include a body must also provide the correct content-type for that body."* adding `content-type: application/json` in the request solved the issue.

[image]